# Required Regex Validation Start two Fixed character and then after Numeric fixed Character

Tags: regex

I Just Update my requirement can you please help me,

Required Regex Validation Start two Fixed character and then after First point required alphanumeric characters and second point required Numeric fixed Character.

Example:

1. if character start with **PB** then allow 25 character

**- Length :** additional 25 numbers.
**- Example :** PB12345Ab8901234567890123mM
If “PB” then 25 alphanumeric characters.
PB+25numbers

2. if character start with **CC** then allow 14 character

**- Length :** additional 14 numbers.
**- Example :** CC012345678901234
If “CC” then 14 numbers.
CC+14numbers

Answer (score -1):

Please try below code

```
var regExString = "PB0123456789012345678901234";

Regex regex ;

if regExString.startwith("PB"){
    regex = new Regex(@"PB[0-9]{25}$");
}
if regExString.startwith("CC"){
    regex = new Regex(@"CC[0-9]{14}$");
}
```

Please let me know the string "PB" and "CC" are fixed or the can be anything.

Comment: Yes, PB and CC is fixed character

Comment: You could also *assemble* it as, e.g., `(?:PB|CC)(?:\d{25}|\d{14})$`

Comment: What? That *copy/pasted* wrong: `(?:PB\d{25}|CC\d{14})$`

Comment: Thanks Piyali Das and Jimi both of your  code helpful me.

Comment: You are most welcome Prakash

Comment: your previous answer work for me but need another requirement Piyali Das and Jimi can you please help me again

Comment: Prakash, Please explain the requirement in details please.

Comment: If ‘AB’ enter AB and 25 characters (AB1234567Cb123456B8912Dc567)

If ‘CC’ enter CC and 14 numbers (CC02345678902345)

Comment: Try this solution: `(?:AB[\da-zA-Z]{25}|CC\d{14})$`
If you want to allow other character also, then use `(?:AB[\d\D]{25}|CC\d{14})$`

Below are some basic rule:
1. Regular expression for any digit from 0-9: \d
2. Regular expression for any character that not digit define by \d: \D
3. Regular expression to match a range of single lower case character: [a-c]
4. Regular expression to match a range of single upper case character: [A-Z]
5. Regular expression to match a range of single case insencetive character: [a-zA-Z]

check https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html

Comment: (?:AB[\da-zA-Z]{25}|CC\d{14})$ i need in this expression add one condition if string not start with AB or CC then it's allow 0 to 100 character.

Comment: (?:PB[A-Za-z0-9]{25}|CC\d{14})$ in this expression add  ^.{0,100}$ this condition.